# Pandas Dataframe: How to update multiple columns by applying a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe df like this:

```
   A   B   C    D
2  1   O   s    h
4  2   P    
7  3   Q
9  4   R   h    m
```

I have a function f to calculate C and D based on B for a row:

```
def f(p): #p is the value of column B for a row. 
     return p+'k', p+'n'
```

How can I populate the missing values for row 4&7 by applying the function f to the Dataframe?

The expected outcome is like below:

```
   A   B   C    D
2  1   O   s    h
4  2   P   Pk   Pn
7  3   Q   Qk   Qn
9  4   R   h    m
```

The function f has to be used as the real function is very complicated. Also, the function only needs to be applied to the rows missing C and D

Comment: May you update the question with the complete function in order to reproduce the whole code?

Comment: Added dummy logic to the function so it returns 2 values.

Comment: what is the expected output? sorry but i do not really get your function ..

Comment: hope the below helps.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe there is a more elegant way, but I would do in this way:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: f(x)[0])
df['D'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: f(x)[1])
```

Applying the function to the columns and get the first and the second value of the outputs. It returns:

```
   A  B   C   D
0  1  O  Ok  On
1  2  P  Pk  Pn
2  3  Q  Qk  Qn
3  4  R  Rk  Rn
```

EDIT:

In a more concise way, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32603811/2699288):

```
df[['C','D']] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([f(x)[0],f(x)[1]]))
```

Comment: The function f has to be used as the real function is very complicated. Also, the function only needs to be applied to the rows missing C and D.

Comment: As long as the function returns two arguments it should work in this way.

Comment: Thanks @Fiabetto. how can we apply the function to only the rows missing values in C and D?

Comment: Ops sorry @ColonelBeauvel, I've been working on that before reading your answer! I've updated the answer with your credits!

Comment: Still, our answer do not answer the question! I edited mine for this purpose.

Comment: I would say that this `df[['C','D']] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(f(x)))` is enough. No need to unpack a list to pack it again.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use your function **as such**, here is a one liner:

```
df.update(df.B.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(zip(['C','D'],f(x))))), overwrite=False)

In [350]: df
Out[350]:
   A  B   C   D
2  1  O   s   h
4  2  P  Pk  Pn
7  3  Q  Qk  Qn
9  4  R   h   m
```

You can also do:

```
df1 = df.copy()

df[['C','D']] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x['B'] + 'k', x['B'] + 'n']), axis=1)

df1.update(df, overwrite=False)
```

Comment: This looks nice but it does not use the function f.

Comment: The solution now uses your function f without remodifying it!

Answer (score 6):

**I have a more easy way to do it, if the table is not so big.**

```
def f(row): #row is the value of row. 
    if row['C']=='':
        row['C']=row['B']+'k'
    if row['D']=='':
        row['D']=row['B']+'n'
    return row
df=df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this super confusing but eventually figured out a way of achieving this that didn't hurt my brain.  Here it is, sorry if it doesn't match the example well...

**dataframe with no index**

```
# function to do the calcs
def f(row):
    my_a = row['a'] # row is a Series, my_a is a scalar string

    if my_a == 'a':  # dummy logic to calc new values based on the row values
        return [1, 2] # return 2 values to update 2 columns
    else:
        return [4, 5]

# simple test frame
input = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'a': ['a', 'd'],
    'b': ['b', 'e'],
    'c': ['c', 'f'],
    'x': [0, 0],
    'y': [0, 0]
})

# apply the function to update the x and y columns with the returned values
input[['x','y']] = input.apply(f, axis=1)
```

**dataframe with an index**

if your dataframe has an index.. you need to be a bit more explicit when you are doing the apply to ensure that "list-like results will be turned into columns"...

```
def f(row): # function to do the calcs
    my_a = row['a'] # row is a Series, my_a is a scalar string
    my_index = row.name # you might also want to use the index value in the calcs

    if my_a == 'a': # dummy logic to calc new values based on the row values
        return [1, 2] # return 2 values to update 2 columns
    else:
        return [4, 5]

input = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'an_index': ['indx1', 'indx2'],
    'a': ['a', 'd'],
    'b': ['b', 'e'],
    'c': ['c', 'f'],
    'x': [0, 0],
    'y': [0, 0]
}).set_index(['an_index'])

# apply the function to update the x and y columns with the returned values
input[['x','y']] = input.apply(f, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 0):

simply by doing the following

```
df.C.loc[df.C.isnull()] = df.B.loc[df.C.isnull()] + 'k'

df.D.loc[df.D.isnull()] = df.B.loc[df.D.isnull()] + 'n'
```

check this link [indexing-view-versus-copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) if you want to know why I've use `loc`